# Why does Python Imports stop working when I switch Python version?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, version, pyautogui

I was working on a project using the 'pyautogui' module, and I needed to switch my python version from the base 3.7.4, to 3.11.6, but when I switch it, it gives an error `'Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source'`. I am currently using VSCode (if this helps).

I have tried deinstalling and reinstalling 'pyautogui; multiple times, but when I do it says, `'Requirement already satisfied.'` I have tried downloading the newest version of conda, and yet, it still says, `"Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source"` from all my debug methods. I have also tried updating pip installer, but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Pythons don't share modules. If you use new Python then you have to install module for this version. it may need to use `pip3.11` instead of `pip3.7` or `pip3`. Or use `python3.11 -m pip install ...`

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a one-to-one correspondence between the Python interpreter and third-party packages. Which environment you install in which package will be used.

If you are confused about the current environment. Use the following code to print the current interpreter path, and then use the command with full paths to install third-party packages.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

*Just an example, modify the path to yours:*

```
E:\Programs\anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install pyautogui
```

If you are using conda, you can also manage it in the **Anacond Navigator**.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to be so late for answering, I did the first part you said, now could you quid me, the print was C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Class\myenv\Scripts\python.exe (I changed my actually name for user).

Comment: quid -> guide, typo

Comment: `C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Class\myenv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install pyautogui`. Spaces in your directory may cause the command to fail.

Comment: I have tried doing that, but it still doesn't work.